# I can't save an barcode image to the folder, I just keep getting this black screen after I save information

Tags: php, image, barcode

This the code where the barcode generate random barcode

```
$barcode = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,13);

$barcodeimg = $barcode.".png";

$stud->generateBarcodeImage($barcode,20,"horizontal","code128","");
```

I don't get this code, I'd research about this but I can't figure it out

```
        // Draw barcode to the screen
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image, "barcode/".$text.".png");
        imagedestroy($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the image data correctly saved in `$image`. And you want to output the image to the screen, dont specify the last parameter in `imagepng($image);`

Comment: My bad, I don't want to output the barcode image in the screen, just after saving the info, it will create the image and save in the barcode folder.

Comment: Hi, um I've managed to save the created barcode image in the folder, which is my goal, but the black screen still there, it's like the broken barcode image, I just want to remove this black screen image thing so that I will not refresh the page everytime I save information,